# How many Kohanim at the time of the MIshkan?

Tags: kohen-priest, dor-hamidbar

After Nadav and Avihu were killed, until Pinchas was proclaimed a Kohen, were there only 3 Kohanim - namely, Aharon, Elazar and Isamor? Is there anything written about this? Is there anything written about this?

Even if they had children, they must have been quite busy in the Mishkan with so few Kohanim. Also, how so few Kohanim were they able to eat from all the korbanos, such as the korban shelomim, which is eaten by the Kohen?

Comment: Note that according to the meforshim that Pinchas was not a kohen because he had been born before Aharon had become kohen gadol, any other children of Elazar and Isamar could not have become kohanim until after Pinchas had been anointed as a kohen or unless they were born after Matan Torah.

Comment: Pinchas was given the Kehuna near the end of the Exodus. We might assume that in the interim, Elazar had had more children and Itamar had children.